# Regex validation doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var validatePassword = function(password) {

    var upper = new RegExp(/^(?=.*[A-Z]).+$/),
    lower = new RegExp(/^(?=.*[a-z]).+$/),
    symbols = new RegExp(/^(?=.*(_|[^\w])).+$/),
    numbers = new RegExp(/^(?=.*\d).+$/);

    if((upper.test(password) && lower.test(password)) || (upper.test(password) && numbers.test(password)) || (upper.test(password) && symbols.test(password)) || (lower.test(password) && numbers.test(password)) || (lower.test(password) && symbols.test(password)))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Invalid password')
    }
}
validatePassword('Foo1!');
});
```

it only return true if any value is entered if i only enter one it returns me true

Comment: can you do jsfiddle of this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8TExU/2/ - can you add more cases like `test('Foo1!', true);` where the second param indicates whether the password is valid or not

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on your comment I've updated my answer:

**The password needs to match at `least two` out of `4 conditions` and have `8 characters` to be `true`**

```
var validatePassword = function(password) {

    var numero = 0;
//check if a digit is present    
if(/(?=.*?[\d]).*$/.test(password)) {
     numero++;
}
//check if a uppercase letter is present  
if(/(?=.*?[A-Z]).*$/.test(password)) {
        numero++;
}
//check if a lowercase letter is present
if(/(?=.*?[a-z]).*$/.test(password)) {
         numero++;
}
//check if a special character is present
if(/(?=.*?(_|[^\w])).*$/.test(password)) {
         numero++;
}
//check if at least 8 characters are present        
if (/^(?=.{8,}).*$/.test(password)) {
    var length = true;
} 

if( numero>=2 && length){

        alert('Valid password');
        console.log(numero);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Invalid password');
        console.log(numero);
    }

}
validatePassword('foo4ogD!');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tuga/S57Bb/4/

Comment: Only two of them can be success full i condition i have is like this

Comment: The password WILL be case sensitive and will follow hotmail’s current password selection criteria which requires users to select the following as mandatory: -! 
5.1. at least 8 characters;! 
5.2. contain at least two of the following: -! 
i) upper case letters! 
ii) lower case letters! 
iii) numbers! 
iv) symbols!

Comment: Ok, I'll do it  like that, stand by.

Comment: just check the code at jsfiddle your link i have updated it but it only gives me one result that is true

Comment: @UzairAhmad **The password needs to match at `least two` out of `4 conditions` to be `true`** as you asked.

Answer (score 1):

You should do:

```
var upper = new RegExp(/^(?=.*[A-Z]).+$/),
    lower = new RegExp(/^(?=.*[a-z]).+$/),
    symbols = new RegExp(/^(?=.*(_|[^\w])).+$/),
    numbers = new RegExp(/^(?=.*\d).+$/);
```

to:

```
var upper = /^(?=.*[A-Z]).+$/,
    lower = /^(?=.*[a-z]).+$/,
    symbols = /^(?=.*(_|[^\w])).+$/,
    numbers = /^(?=.*\d).+$/;
```

Your regex is already a regex. You don't need to use `new RegExp("patter","flag");`

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify the logic first

```
var upper = new RegExp(/^(?=.*[A-Z]).+$/),
    lower = new RegExp(/^(?=.*[a-z]).+$/),
    symbols = new RegExp(/^(?=.*(_|[^\w])).+$/),
    numbers = new RegExp(/^(?=.*\d).+$/);
```

Above can be simplified

```
var upper = /[A-Z]/,       // means it contains uppercase
    lower = /[a-z]/,       // means it contains lowercase
    symbols = /[\W_]/,     // means it contains non-word character or underscore
    numbers = /\d/;        // means it contains number
```

Also here

```
// means must have (upper AND lower) OR ((upper OR lower) AND (symbol OR number))
if( 
    (upper.test(password) && lower.test(password)) ||
    (upper.test(password) && numbers.test(password)) ||
    (upper.test(password) && symbols.test(password)) ||
    (lower.test(password) && numbers.test(password)) ||
    (lower.test(password) && symbols.test(password))
  )
```

Above can be simplified

```
// means must have (upper AND lower) OR ((upper OR lower) AND (symbol OR number))
if(
    (upper.test(password) && lower.test(password)) ||
    ((upper.test(password) || lower.test(password)) &&
    (symbols.test(password) || symbols.test(password)))
  )
```

Since it can be (upper AND lower) only

```
upper.test(password) && lower.test(password)
```

It can be tested with

```
var upandlow = /[a-z][A-Z]|[A-Z][a-z]/;
```

Since it must have (upper OR lower), then it can also be checked in ONE step

```
var upperlower = /[a-zA-Z]/;   // means it contains uppercase OR lowercase
```

Since it must have (symbol OR number), then it can also be checked in ONE step

```
var symbolsnumbers = /[\d\W_]/; // means it contains number OR non-word OR underscore
```

Now the whole function can be simplified

```
var validatePassword = function(password) {

  var upandlow = /[a-z][A-Z]|[A-Z][a-z]/,
      upperlower = /[a-zA-Z]/, 
      symbolsnumbers = /[\d\W_]/;

  if ( 
    upandlow.test(password) ||
    (upperlower.test(password) &&  symbolsnumbers.test(password))) {
      console.log('true');
      return true;
  }
  else {
      //alert('Invalid password');
      console.log('Invalid');
  }
}


validatePassword('Foo!');
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9LnP9/)

Good luck
:)